# Unable to INSERT dates and times into MYSQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build an SQL query that will insert the check-in time for a child at a fictional daycare facility. Here is a condensed version of my query code:

```
$childFirstName = $_POST['childFirstName'];
$childLastName = $_POST['childLastName'];

$now = new DateTime();
$nowDate = $now->format('m-d-Y');
$nowTime = $now->format('h:i');


$sql_childID = "SELECT id FROM child
                WHERE firstName = '$childFirstName'
                AND lastName = '$childLastName'";
$result = $pdo->query($sql_childID);
$row = $result->fetch();


$sql = "INSERT INTO checkinout(date, in, child_id) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(1, $nowDate);
    $statement->bindValue(2, $nowTime);
    $statement->bindValue(3, $row['id']);
    $statement->execute();
```

The checkinout table uses VARCHAR datatypes for the *date* and *in* columns. Originally they were set to use DATETIME, but I received the same errors.

Right now I get the following errors returned...

[image]

You can see from the error messages that my values are getting passed in the way I want them to, but I don't understand where my syntax error would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose your field names with backticks. Two of them are reserved words (`date` and `in`):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO checkinout(`date`, `in`, `child_id`) VALUES(?,?,?)";
```

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: UPDATE....I didn't realize a backtick was different from a single quote. Makes me wonder how many other times I might have missed that. Thank you for your help and the link. This solved my problem.